# Get value from multiple select dropdown on Yii to be inserted to database

Tags: yii, controller, dropdown, multiple-select

Help I want to get value from a multiple select dropdown from a form to a controller.

Here's my form:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="form-field-select-4" class="form-control search-select" name="tim_teknis">
    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
</select>
```

And here's my controller:

```
$tim_teknis = $_POST['tim_teknis'];
```

It turned out to be showed like this: "tim_teknis" not the value of the dropdown. I hope anyone could understand what I mean. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You have to implode the values before insert

Answer (score -1):

May be your form not method is 'POST' , so "tim_teknis" not the value of the dropdown.
Solution:

```
<form action="submit_form.php" method="POST"><select multiple="multiple" id="form-field-select-4" class="form-control search-select" name="tim_teknis[]"><option value="">&nbsp;</option><option value="AL">Alabama</option><option value="AK">Alaska</option></select></form><?php if (!empty($_POST['tim_teknis'])) {var_dump($_POST['tim_teknis']);}?>
```

Result after submit form:
`array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "AL" [1]=> string(2) "AK" }`